# Ajuda com lógica - Verificar se o pedido foi feito com muita antecedência

Tags: vba, lógica

Estou desenvolvendo um *script* em *vba*, no *Outlook*, para que ele salve todos os anexos que chegarem com os e-mail novos, com extensão ***xlsx***. Ele verifica se é o anexo certo (através de um código que a planilha terá), copia todo o conteúdo desse *Workbook* (se ele for o correto) para um outro e envia uma resposta automaticamente, para o remetente do e-mail. Tudo isso está funcionando perfeitamente.

Na coluna G, dessa planilha que chega por e-mail, tem uma lista com os meses (que representa o mês de aniversário da pessoa). Caso a solicitação venha com mais de dois meses de antecedência, eu gostaria que a resposta automática tivesse uma observação para aquela solicitação.

Por exemplo: Estamos no mês de Dezembro. As solicitações só podem ser feitas para os meses de Dezembro, Janeiro e Fevereiro. Então se, em alguma linha da planilha, tiver uma solicitação para os meses que não sejam esses, o texto da resposta automática teria um trecho acrescido.

Esse é o problema. Eu não estou conseguindo pensar em uma lógica que faça essa verificação, corretamente.

Edit:
Abaixo escrevi um trecho de código bem próximo ao que estou usando (a lógica é a mesma, só não tenho ele aqui):

```
Dim mesHoje As Integer, mesSolicitacao As Integer    

...
For i=6 To ultimaLinha
        If Plan1.Cells(i, "G") = "Janeiro" Then
           mesSolicitacao = 1
        ElseIf Plan1.Cells(i, "G") = "Fevereiro" Then
           mesSolicitacao = 2

          ...

        ElseIf Plan1.Cells(i, "G") = "Dezembro" Then
           mesSolicitacao = 12
        End If


        mesHoje = Month(Date)


        If Abs((mesHoje + 2) - mesSolicitacao) <= 2 Then '<~ Esse if que eu não estou conseguindo pensar em uma forma de fazer, do jeito que eu quero. Talvez com um if só não da.
            'Rotina para solicitação feita dentro do prazo
        Else
            'Rotina para solicitação feita fora de prazo
        End If
Next
```

Edit:
Acredito que encontrei a solução (não fiz todos os testes, mas dos muitos que fiz, no *excel* mesmo, deram certo). Só troquei o *if* pelo do código abaixo. Mas teria uma forma mais "limpa" de escrever esse trecho?

```
If mesHoje < 11 Then
    If ((mesHoje + 2) - mesSolicitacao) <= 2 And ((mesHoje + 2) - mesSolicitacao) > (-1) Then
        'Rotina para solicitação feita dentro do prazo
    Else
        'Rotina para solicitação feita fora do prazo
    End If
ElseIf mesHoje = 11 Then
    If (mesHoje = 11 And mesSolicitacao = 11) Or (mesHoje = 11 And mesSolicitacao = 12) Or (mesHoje = 11 And mesSolicitacao = 1) Then
        'Rotina para solicitação feita dentro do prazo
    Else
        'Rotina para solicitação feita fora do prazo
    End If
ElseIf mesHoje = 12 Then
    If (mesHoje = 12 And mesSolicitacao = 12) Or (mesHoje = 12 And mesSolicitacao = 1) Or (mesHoje = 12 And mesSolicitacao = 2) Then
        'Rotina para solicitação feita dentro do prazo
    Else
        'Rotina para solicitação feita fora do prazo
    End If
End If
```

Comment: O que você precisa então é de uma função que receba um mês como string e retorne verdadeiro caso esse mês seja daqui a no máximo dois meses e falso caso contrário?

Comment: exatamente, @Pablo. Tentei fazer um _if_, para verificar isso. Mas ele não deu sempre certo. Dava errado, principalmente, nos meses de Novembro e Dezembro

Comment: Pode colocar o código que já tem?

Comment: Código adicionado na pergunta

Comment: Pensei em várias formas aqui de deixar o seu código menor, mas isso afetou a clareza. O que eu recomendo apenas é que separe em funções. Por exemplo, crie a função estaDentroDoPrazo que recebe um mês e retorna um Boolean. Isso já vai ajudar a deixar mais claro.

Comment: Obrigado pela sugestão, @Pablo. Estou alterando para funções, como eu já havia feito, com a rotina de encaminhar e-mails.